# can not connect to XMPP server (Openfire) using XMPP android client

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have openfire installed on remote server. I can connect to it using the Spark XMPP client. But I am getting connection error when I use my Android XMPP client. Here is the connection code part of the Android client application:

```
// Create a connection
    String serverIp = "14.63.XXX.XXX";
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(serverIp, 5222);
    connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);


    try {
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }
    try {
        connection.login(username, password);
         .......
```

I am getting error when connection.connect(); is executed.
I checked the port at the server and its open. I also tried 5223 port. I checked the permission on XMPP client also. I googled it and couldn't find a solution that fix this problem. Can anybody please suggest me what to do?

Comment: have you check all necessary
 information for it??

Comment: You missed an important piece of information: what error are you getting? :)

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have checked everything. Also I tried different possible ways. I even tried the XMPP sample from http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking-tutorials/551-how-write-simple-xmpp-jabber-client-using-smack-api.html and it works with my server. But when I use the same class with the android (by removing MessageListener Implementation), still doesn't work. Now the error becomes when ConnectionConfiguration is created!!!

Comment: @MattJ I don't exactly get the error because on eclipse it says Source not found. P.s see my above comment also. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found temporary solution :).. I put the connection part of the code in  AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Now it works fine but I did other stuffs also, I used the smack API library from another project on the web that is already working.. So Im still searching for smack api that works with my project. I have seen http://asmack.org.. but didn't work for me!!